# How do you change the default font in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi-7

I was wondering if it is possible to change the default font for delphi's forms, instead of having to edit it whenever you make a new project.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Sorry if its a stupid question but thanks!

Comment: It's been awhile since I used Delphi 7, but look under the menu Tools/Options/Editor Options/Display.  This is where it is under Delphi XE2.  It's most likely under something similar in Delphi 7.

Comment: @Mike, that's for the code editor font. The question asks for setting default font for the forms that you create in designer. Personally, I don't know about such setting, but at least you can make a form template, or from 3rd party solutions, e.g. CnPack has the Property Corrector enhancement which allows you to modify set of configured properties for a certain class at one click.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Thanks!

Comment: In addition to @TLama's suggestion, in D2007 and later (don't know if it was around in D7, though) you can set it in a single line of code in your project file with `Application.DefaultFont` before the first call to `Application.CreateForm` is made. This is of course not effective in the IDE itself, but it will change the font on all your forms at once as long as their `ParentFont` property is set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a form and then inherit from it. (File —> New —> Other —> Your_project_name tab)